# How can I make a generic IQueryable in Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, generics, c#-3.0, iqueryable

I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC project and I have this particular situation: I have 3 pages - Product, Order, User. And in each of these pages I have a link calling the same ActionResult differing only by the argument passed depending on the page I'm in. For example:

```
public ActionResult(string typeOfPage)
{
   if (typeOfPage == "User")
   {
      //do something
   }
   else if (typeOfPage == "Product")
   {
      //do other things
   }
}
```

What I want to do now is to get all data from DB depending on "typeOfPage" value. And, of course, in **dbml**, all the entities have the same name as the typeOfPage value (User, Product, Order).

I'm trying to avoid doing a specific IQueryable for each page, depending on typeOfPage value.

Is there a way to get this typeOfPage string value, get an Entity with the same name and use an IQueryable to get all data from this Entity??

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

See my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
```

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Repository : IRepository
        where TModel : class, new()
    {
        public DataContext dc;
        public string pk { get; set; }
        public Repository(DataContext dc)
        {
            this.dc = dc;
        }

```
    #region IRepository<TKeyType,TModel> 

    public IQueryable<TModel> getAllEntries()
    {
        return dc.GetTable<TModel>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;


namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Repository : IRepository
        where TModel : class, new()
    {
        public DataContext dc;
        public string pk { get; set; }
        public Repository(DataContext dc)
        {
            this.dc = dc;
        }

        #region IRepository 

        public IQueryable getAllEntries()
        {
            return dc.GetTable();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class NorthwindController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Northwind/
        NorthwindDataContext dc;
        Repository prdRepostory;
        Repository cstrRepostory;
        public NorthwindController()
        {
            this.dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
            prdRepostory = new Repository(dc);
            cstrRepostory = new Repository(dc);
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string typeOfString)
        {
            if (typeOfString == "Products")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("getProducts");
            }
            else if (typeOfString == "Customers")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("getCustomers");
            }
            else return View();
        }

        public ActionResult getProducts()
        {
            return View(prdRepostory.getAllEntries());
        }
        public ActionResult getCustomers()
        {
            return View(cstrRepostory.getAllEntries());
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you should refer to the codeplex project [MVCCRUD](http://mvccrud.codeplex.com/) which is exactly what you want . Good luck !